# C# SQL Web Application - My Web App will not perform necessary update/deletes when method is called

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am literally stumped. I've spent two days working at this. I have tried scrolling through the internet but nothing I seem to try worked like try/catch blocks, using etc.

So here goes..

I have a Web Application asp c# , which is connected to an sql database that I have written within Visual Studio 'Database.mdf' .

The Database contains a number of Football Players and their details, I want to be able to update and delete these details however my sql commands are not coming into affect (I am new to this so it's probably something ridiculously simple to most of you but nonetheless)

I have a number of buttons in which I use to both sort the data on screen in order. They work fine, I just use a static variable string for that. However the methods I have written for the SQL Commands are not working for me. The methods are called also on Button_Click but in the case of Update/Delete nothing changes, it's as if the sql query never updated the database

Please if you have any idea how I can fix this let me know. My head's fried.

Here are a few of the methods including display data :

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\WebApplication5\\WebApplication5\\App_Data\\Database2.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
        cn = new SqlConnection(str);
        cn.Open();
        mycount();
        displayData();
    //    updateData();
    //    deleteData();


    }



    protected void mycount()
    {   // count no of els in table
        max = 0;
        var cmd = cn.CreateCommand();


        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) max++;
        reader.Close();
    }

    protected void displayData()
    {


            var cmd = cn.CreateCommand();


            cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) reader.Read();
            TextBox1.Text = "" + reader[0];
            TextBox2.Text = "" + reader[1];
            TextBox5.Text = "" + reader[2];
            TextBox6.Text = "" + reader[3];
            TextBox7.Text = "" + reader[4];
            TextBox8.Text = "" + reader[5];
            reader.Close();


    }

protected void updateData()
{
    var cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
    string query = "UPDATE [Footballer] SET [Appearances] = @appear , [NumberOfGoals] = @goals Where [PlayerName] = @name ";
    cmd.CommandText = query;

    int appear = int.Parse(TextBox6.Text);
    int goals = int.Parse(TextBox8.Text);
    string name = TextBox1.Text;


     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Player_ID", name);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@app", appear);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@goals", goals);


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}


protected void deleteData()
{
    string searchName = TextBox4.Text;
    TextBox1.Text = "Deleted";
    TextBox2.Text = "Deleted";
    TextBox5.Text = "Deleted";
    TextBox6.Text = "Deleted";
    TextBox7.Text = "Deleted";
    TextBox8.Text = "Deleted";
    var cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
    string query = "Delete from [Footballer] where [PlayerName] = @PlayerName_ID";

    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerName_ID", searchName);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Here is a screen of what I got visually if it helps:

[Gui View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uUhE.png)

Comment: i see the tag `mysql` but don't see mysql mentioned anywhere in the code - am i missing something?

Comment: did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: @JohnB you're right, error on my part. Not thinking straight. There aren't any errors or warnings. As far as debugging all I've done is pass the same commands to the database using add query. I'll try the debugger now.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably because you do not commit the transaction. There is an example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit